# Are there constants for language codes in java or in a java library?

Tags: java, internationalization, locale, constants

Are there any constants for language codes like `"en"` or `"de"` in java or in a java library? (Or is using the strings OK?)

I know that something like

```
Locale.COUNTRY-NAME.getLanguage()
```

would work, but I am searching for something more streamlined like

```
Locale.LANGUAGE-NAME
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am afraid there aren't constants for all languages.
You do have several predefined Locales such as `Locale.UK` `Locale.US`, etc. Each locale has a language code which can be obtained via the `getLanguage()` method.

To get all language code supported by the underlying JVM use `getISOLanguages()`

```
for(String lang : Locale.getISOLanguages()) {
  System.out.println(lang);
}
```

More details: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html

Answer (score 8):

The 2-letter language codes are defined by ISO 639-1 standard. The `java.util.Locale` class does not contain them all, but only Locales supported by the VM (as per `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`).

The easiest way to access all ISO 639-1 language codes in Java is to rely on the [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/) project (ICU4J) — an extensive, widely used and actively developed i18n library from IBM. You can get the list of all languages from the ULocale class: [com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale.getISOLanguages()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/ULocale.html#getISOLanguages%28%29).

Comment: It's ISO 639-1, not 639-2. Otherwise, +1.

Answer (score -2):

Yup.. Use `Locale.COUNTRY-NAME`

Comment: Not the same thing. Martin's looking for *language* codes, not *country* codes. They don't necessarily map 1:1 to each other.

Comment: you can use locale to get the language like so `Locale local = Locale.ENGLISH; local.getLanguage();`